# Performing part of a IQueryable query and deferring the rest to Linq for Objects

Tags: c#, linq, expression-trees, iqueryable

I have a Linq provider that sucessfully goes and gets data from my chosen datasource, but what I would like to do now that I have my filtered resultset, is allow Linq to Objects to process the rest of the Expression tree (for things like Joins, projection etc)

My thought was that I could just replace the expression constant that contains my IQueryProvider with the result-sets IEnumerable via an ExpressionVisitor and then return that new expression. Also return the IEnumerable's provider from my IQueryable...but this does not seem to work :-(

Any idea's?

Edit:
Some good answers here, but given the form...

```
var qry = from c in MyProv.Table<Customer>()
          Join o in MyProv.Table<Order>() on c.OrderID equals o.ID
          select new 
          {
            CustID = c.ID,
            OrderID = o.ID
          }
```

In my provider I can easily get back the 2 resultsets from Customers and Orders, if the data was from a SQL source I would just construct and pass on the SQL Join syntax, but it this case the data is not from a SQL source so I need to do the join in code...but as I said I have the 2 result sets, and Linq to Objects can do a join...(and later the projection) it would be real nice to just substitute the Expression constants `MyProv.Table<Customer>` and `MyProv.Table<Order>` with `List<Customer>` and `List<Order>` and let a `List<>` provider process the expression...is that possible? how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The kind of thing that I was after was replacing the Queryable<> constant in the expression tree with a concrete IEnumerable (or IQueryable via .AsQueryable()) result set...this is a complex topic that probably only makes any sense to Linq Provider writers who are knee deep in expression tree visitors etc.

I found a snippet on the msdn walkthrough that does something like what I am after, this gives me a way forward...

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace LinqToTerraServerProvider
{
    internal class ExpressionTreeModifier : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        private IQueryable<Place> queryablePlaces;

        internal ExpressionTreeModifier(IQueryable<Place> places)
        {
            this.queryablePlaces = places;
        }

        internal Expression CopyAndModify(Expression expression)
        {
            return this.Visit(expression);
        }

        protected override Expression VisitConstant(ConstantExpression c)
        {
            // Replace the constant QueryableTerraServerData arg with the queryable Place collection.
            if (c.Type == typeof(QueryableTerraServerData<Place>))
                return Expression.Constant(this.queryablePlaces);
            else
                return c;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I thank you from my knees - deep in expression tree visitors. :) This is exactly what I needed

Answer (score 6):

Both of the previous answers work, but it reads better if you use AsEnumerable() to cast the IQueryable to IEnumerable:

```
// Using Bob's code...
var result = datacontext.Table
   .Where(x => x.Prop == val)
   .OrderBy(x => x.Prop2)
   .AsEnumerable()  //  <---- anything after this is done by LINQ to Objects
   .Select(x => new { CoolProperty = x.Prop, OtherProperty = x.Prop2 });
```

EDIT:

```
// ... or MichaelGG's
var res = dc.Foos
           .Where(x => x.Bla > 0)  // uses IQueryable provider
           .AsEnumerable()
           .Where(y => y.Snag > 0); // IEnumerable, uses LINQ to Objects
```

Answer (score 2):

If you implemented a Repository Pattern you could get away with just providing an IQueryable back and abstract away the table.

Example:

```
var qry = from c in MyProv.Repository<Customer>()
          Join o in MyProv.Repository<Order>() on c.OrderID equals o.ID
          select new 
          {
            CustID = c.ID,
            OrderID = o.ID
          }
```

and then just build your provider to model the IQueryable pattern in your Repository method just like [this article](http://iridescence.no/post/Linq-to-Sql-Programming-Against-an-Interface-and-the-Repository-Pattern.aspx) illustrates.

This way, you can write all kinds of providers to use for whatever you need. You can have a LINQ 2 SQL provider, or write an in memory provider for your unit tests.

The Repository method for the LINQ 2 SQL provider would look something like this:

```
public IQueryable<T> Repository<T>() where T : class
{
    ITable table = _context.GetTable(typeof(T));
    return table.Cast<T>();
}
```

Comment: Very interesting, I will play around with this, this weekend.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm misunderstanding, I generally just add .ToArray() in the chain of linq methods at the point where I want the linq provider to execute.

For example (think Linq to SQL)

```
var result = datacontext.Table
   .Where(x => x.Prop == val)
   .OrderBy(x => x.Prop2)
   .ToArray()
   .Select(x => new {CoolProperty = x.Prop, OtherProperty = x.Prop2});
```

So through OrderBy() gets translated into SQL, but the Select() is LINQ to Objects.

Answer (score 0):

Rob's answer is good, but forces full enumeration. You could cast to keep extension method syntax and lazy evaluation:

```
var res = ((IEnumerable<Foo>)dc.Foos
            .Where(x => x.Bla > 0))  // IQueryable
          .Where(y => y.Snag > 0)   // IEnumerable
```