# Easiest way to find a particular string from comma separated strings

Tags: c#, csv

I have to fetch distinct values from a comma separated string.The input string can contain duplicate values.This is for auto-complete feature.
For example:

I have a string: **shop,dell,image,just,just do,file,just,do,shop....** 
My requirement is that when I pass '**jus**', the output string should be: "**just,just do**".

Comment: I have converted the string into array using string.split(,) and then searched in the array.

Comment: Of the two solutions provided, which of them is the fastest? because the input string is going to be huge..

Comment: There is no difference between using LINQ through keywords or through a method chain; both get compiled to the same IL (`http://stackoverflow.com/a/16487601/1937294`). It seems like the efficiency is debated (`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1182922/what-is-the-efficiency-and-performance-of-linq-and-lambda-expression-in-net`), but your original question asks for the easiest way.

Comment: @Andrew thanks for the explanation.Performance is the most important factor for me as well as the code shouldn't be too complex.Your code satisfies my requirements.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var csv = "shop,dell,image,just,just do,file,just,do,shop";
var arr = csv.Split(',');

var suggested = from word in arr
                where word.StartsWith("jus")
                select word;
suggested = suggested.Distinct();
```

To explain this code line by line:

1. Create variable called `csv` that contains the text
2. Split the string into multiple strings using the `Split` function
3. Use a LINQ query to only get text you want, i.e.: *select the strings that start with "jus", in this case.*
4. Use the `Distinct` method to remove the duplicate entries from the list.

Comment: Of the two solutions provided, which of them is the fastest? because the input string is going to be huge..

Comment: @nitinvertigo They will probably be pretty much identical in speed. They both use `Distinct()` which will be the slowest bit.

Answer (score 4):

You will want to split your string by commas and then search the resulting strings.

```
string csvList = "shop,dell,image,just,just do,file,just,do,shop";
string search = "jus"; // your search string goes here
var splitResults = csvList.Split(',').ToList();
// improvement: cache SplitResults once, and retrieve it from cache on every search
var searchResults = splitResults.Where(x => x.StartsWith(search)).Distinct();
```

You can change the last line to use `Contains` to search within words or use `StartsWith(search, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)` to ignore case where searching.

In the case of a very large input, you should be caching the `List<string> splitResults` so that you have the search items ready to go. If you have high volume, you definitely do not want to be splitting the `csvList` every single time that it is searched.